# How to remove all the variable that named as .x, .y?

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frame (lst1). In each data.frame in lst1, we have some variables that looks like test.x, test.y, try.x, try.y. etc.

I want to filter out those variables that were created by merging dataset without filter out those variable first (try, test, etc.). How should I filter them out now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach:

We can use the `dplyr::select` function to select only the columns we want. `matches()` allows us to select columns using regular expressions. `\\.[xy]$` matches columns that contain a period followed by `x` or `y` and `$` anchors the match to the end of the string.

The `purrr::map` function allows us to apply the selection to each list element. `~` defines a formula which is automatically converted to a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
lst2 <- lst1 %>%
  map(~dplyr::select(.,-matches("\\.[xy]$")))

map(lst2, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#  ID name
#1  1    A
#2  2    B
#[[2]]
#  ID name
#1  1    A
#2  2    B
#[[3]]
#  ID name
#1  1    A
#2  2    B
#[[4]]
#  ID name
#1  1    A
#2  2    B
#[[5]]
#  ID name
#1  1    A
#2  2    B
```

Sample Data:

```
lst1 <- replicate(5,data.frame(ID = 1:15, name = LETTERS[1:15], test.x = runif(15), test.y = runif(15)),simplify = FALSE)
map(lst1, head, 2)
#[[1]]
#  ID name     test.x    test.y
#1  1    A 0.03772391 0.2630905
#2  2    B 0.11844048 0.2929392
#[[2]]
#  ID name   test.x    test.y
#1  1    A 0.398029 0.5151159
#2  2    B 0.348489 0.9534869
#[[3]]
#  ID name    test.x    test.y
#1  1    A 0.7447383 0.6862136
#2  2    B 0.3623562 0.7542699
#
#[[4]]
#  ID name    test.x    test.y
#1  1    A 0.9341495 0.8660333
#2  2    B 0.8383039 0.6299427
#[[5]]
#  ID name     test.x     test.y
#1  1    A 0.02662444 0.04502225
#2  2    B 0.29855214 0.46189116
```

Comment: Ah - yes, it does it's own packaging. Your comment about `$` is the working version

Comment: If I am dealing with a dataframe `df`, can I do the same thing `df %>% select(-match("\\.[xy]$"))`? I tried it and get the error message `Error: argument "table" is missing, with no default`. How should I correct it?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this:

```
#Data
List <- list(A=data.frame(a=1,b=5,test.x=NA,test.y=5),
             B=data.frame(a=5,b=6,test.x=NA,try.x=7))
#Remove
myfun <- function(x)
{
  i <- which(grepl('.x|.y',names(x)))
  x <- x[,-i]
  return(x)
}
#Apply
List2 <- lapply(List,myfun)
```

Output:

```
List2
$A
  a b
1 1 5

$B
  a b
1 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `endsWith`

```
lapply(List, function(x) x[!(endsWith(names(x), 
        '.x')|endsWith(names(x), '.y'))])
```

-output

```
#$A
#  a b
#1 1 5

#$B
#  a b
#1 5 6
```

#### data

```
List <- list(A = structure(list(a = 1, b = 5, test.x = NA, test.y = 5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), B = structure(list(a = 5, b = 6, test.x = NA, try.x = 7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)))
```